# Когда использовать статический и динамический класс?

Tags: php, ооп

Всем привет! Пишу сайт на php и понял, что зарос на нём статическими классами и методами. Хочу понять поподробнее разницу и желательно с примерами на каждый, когда использовать статический, а когда динамический класс/метод. Да возможно вопрос странный, но хочется на этом поставить точку. Буду признателен вашим ответам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нет причин для создания экземпляров класса, то он статичный, иначе динамический.
Пример статического, класса Math - он содержит в себе константы PI и E, а так же разные математический функции, такие как SIN, COS, ABS.. - нет смысла создавать экземпляр такого класса. С другой стороны есть класс Person обладающий индивидуальными значениями полей - такой класс должен быть динамический, чтобы была возможность менять значения переменных, как-то их хранить(в массиве, например) и как-то с ними работать(сравнивать между собой..).